# How to get a dynamic path during runtime?

Tags: delphi, path, delphi-7

I have problems with getting the specific path of an image file that is uploaded to my application during runtime and I would love some help.

Basically I am trying to save a picture to a database, and I can partly achieve that. I am using the following:

```
procedure TForm12.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOQuery4.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Profile_Picture, username FROM profile WHERE username='+QuotedStr(edit12.Text);
ADOQuery4.Open();
ADOQuery4.Edit();
TBlobField(ADOQuery4.FieldByName('Profile_Picture')).LoadFromFile('aaa.jpg');
ADOQuery4.Post();
end;
```

The code selects the correct place I want it to be places in the database, and correctly updates it with the file I have selected (the aaa.jpg file).
But this works only if I program it as such and it cannot be changed during runtime, in other words the user of the application cannot change the file throught the interface unless he opens the whole thing and change the code.

What I am asking is, is it possible to get the path of a file through a command during runtime?
For example, if I wanna save whatever picture is uploaded with an OpenPictureDialog component, how is it possible to do that? To select whatever specific file is selected by the OpenPictureDialog during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TOpenPictureDialog` tells you the full path of the selected file, eg:

```
procedure TForm12.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    ...
    TBlobField(ADOQuery4.FieldByName('Profile_Picture')).LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
    ...
  end;
end;
```